# Nyromodal manual mode ignore parameters

Tags: jquery, nyromodal

I'm currently use [nyromodal](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/) in a website but I have some trouble to set the sizes.
Actually, I do something like this :

```
$.nmManual(
  '#agenda-edit',{              
    resizable: true,
sizes: {    // Size information
  w: 500,   // Initial width
  h: 500    // Initial height
}
  }
);
```

But It won't work, any idea ?

Comment: Do you need to change the min width/height?

Comment: `resizable` is not an option of nyroModal v2. Are you using a previous version?

Comment: I'm currently using the version 2.0 of nyroModal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the width of the nyromodal window just change this css line :

```
.nyroModalCont {
    width: 800px;
```

By your value

Answer (score 1):

use **minH** and **minW**
like

```
sizes: {
 minH : 500,
 minW : 500
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some tests using `$.nmManual` with a DOM selector. NyroModal will set the max  dimensions of the DOM element according to the css class selector `.nyroModalDom`.
So you could set width and heigth through the css class selector `.nyroModalDom` but then nyroModal doesn't perform any resizing of the DOM element after a window resizing.

Comment: I have change a few lines of css and I can resize the modal window

Comment: Could you explain me your changes, please? Using manually nyroModal I'm not been able to solve this issue so far.